# Can you change the criterial for the AutoFilter method?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have a bunch of devices, and I want to filter these, then lookup a specific value, and then clear that filter and filter again using a new value.

This is the code I stole from Trump Excel example:
https://trumpexcel.com/vba-autofilter/

```
    Sub FilterRows()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, 
    Criteria1:="Printer"
    End Sub
```

So, once filtered, say I want to find a specific value associated with that row, then clear the filter and use "white board" look up the specific value and then clear that filter and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this what you're getting at?

```
Sub FilterRows(ByVal criterion As String)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:=criterion 
End Sub


Sub main()
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item in Array("Printer","Whiteboard",...) 'or read from a range
        FilterRows item 'pass the criteria as string arguments
        'now do whatever to read the value
    Next item
End Sub
```

I think the AutoFilter method should overwrite the previous filter

Comment: You have a missing line separator after `...Field:=2,`. It should be `...Field:=2, _`. Since you are using `item` in a `For Each Next` loop, it has to be declared as `Variant`: `Dim item As Variant`. Confirming that each time only the new filter will be applied (in regards to  *I think the AutoFilter method should overwrite the previous filter*).